# How to split text after checking length in Google Sheets?

Tags: excel, google-sheets

How do I split contents of a cell if the cell is not empty in Google spread sheet?

```
Name    | DOB        | Day | Month | Year
------------------------------------------
John    | 01/01/1995 | 1   | 1     | 1995
Doe     |            |     |       |
Dane    | 10/05/1988 | 10  | 5     | 1988
```

Since Doe doesn't have a date of birth, the value for day, month and year is empty.

I am currently using

```
=ArrayFormula(SPLIT(B1,"/"))
```

How to check the condition before splitting?

Comment: Use `=IF(B1="","",arrayformula)`

Comment: Thank you @GowthamShiva. Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting the answer as it worked for you,

```
=IF(B1="","",arrayformula)
```

Answer (score 0):

There seems no need to make any special provision for blanks (nor need for any formula). Copy the DOB column (excluding header) under `Day` and apply Data > Split text into columns... with Custom Separator of `/`.